# Can I use both optional positional parameters and named parameters in the same function with Dart?

Tags: function, dart

I assume that Dart doesn't allow for both named and optional positional parameters. Am I correct in assuming this? Is there a way that I can create this function without having to use a named parameter for the second string?

Here is my function:

```
void log(Object? s,{ int priority = 1,LogType logType = LogType.misc,bool on = true}){
  if (priority >= lowestDisplayedPriority && (activeLogs.contains(logType)) && on){
    print('='+s.toString());
  }
}
```

I want to turn the function into the following:

```
void log(Object? s,[Object? s2 = ''],{ int priority = 1,LogType logType = LogType.misc,bool on = true}){
  if (priority >= lowestDisplayedPriority && (activeLogs.contains(logType)) && on){
    print('='+s.toString());
    if(s2 != ''){
      print('='+s2.toString());
    }  
  }
}
```

I get an error which says "Expected to find ')'."

My desired function's usage would be something like this:

`log(A,B, priority : 2)` or `log(A, priority : 2)`

Comment: If you called `log(A,B)`, how is it to know if `B` is an `s2` or a `priority`?

Comment: An example would be `log(A,B, priority : 2)` or `log(A, priority : 2)`

Comment: It's not currently possible to have both named and optional positional parameters.  See: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1076

Comment: @ScottHunter There would be no ambiguity. For log`(A, B)`, `B` is positional and not named and therefore would be `s2`.  Unlike Python, parameters are positional *or* named, never both.  Arguments for named parameters must *always* be named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not yet possible. Please keep upvoting https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1076

Two alternatives came to mind you could use today:

### Use a list as first parameter

This way you always have to provide a list, which sucks for single arguments. But it works quite well.

```dart
void main() {
  log([1, 2], priority: Priority.low);
  log(['a', 'b', 'c'], priority: Priority.high);
  log(['hello']);
  // low: 1, 2
  // high: a, b, c
  // low: hello
}


void log(List<Object?> args, {Priority priority = Priority.low}) {
  final text = args.join(', ');
  print('${priority.name}: $text');
}

enum Priority {
  low,
  high,
}
```

### Filter special types from args as options

This doesn't give you named parameters, but it might be easier to call for single arguments.

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  log(1, 2, Priority.low);
  log('a', 'b', 'c', Priority.high);
  log('hello');
  // low: 1, 2
  // high: a, b, c
  // low: hello
}

void log([
  Object a0 = _default,
  Object a1 = _default,
  Object a2 = _default,
  Object a3 = _default,
]) {
  final allArgs = [a0, a1, a2, a3].where((it) => it != _default);
  final priority = allArgs.whereType<Priority>().firstOrNull ?? Priority.low;
  final text = allArgs.where((it) => it is! Priority).join(', ');

  print('${priority.name}: $text');
}

enum Priority {
  low,
  high,
}

const Object _default = Object();
```

Comment: This will definitely achieve my intended functionality. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@jamerdlin Answered my question. It is not currently possible (2023/03/22).

My solution is to create another function to let take in a List<Object?> where I can print multiple things when needed.